# Form to Form jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, select, input

I've been working on a piece of code for a bit now. I have the bulk of the code, but the actual transfer of forms is throwing me off.

```
$("#shrimpfrm").children().map(function() {
    var child = $(this);
    var value = child.val();
    var container = $("#shrimpMaster");
    var field = $("<input />");

    if (child.is(":select")) {
        $(container) 
            // THIS IS WHERE I'M LOST 

    }

    return null;
});
```

I need to add the value of any select box in `#shrimpfrm` to a text box in `#shrimpMaster`. The text boxs actually have to be created in `#shrimpMaster` I believe I have the proper function set, and all the variables in place, I just don't know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your specific HTML, and without knowing the relationship between the two forms, I'd suggest:

```
$('#shrimpfrm select').each(
    function(){
        $('<input />').val($(this).val()).appendTo($('#shrimpMaster'));
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6MRYB/).

This will find all the `select` elements within the `#shrimpfrm` form, create an `input` (which defaults to `type="text"`) with the value from the current `select` and then append that to the `#shrimpMaster` form.

To do this in response to a change made to a `select`:

```
$('select').change(
    function() {
        $('#shrimpMaster input:text').remove();
        $('#shrimpfrm select')
            .each(
                function(){
                    $('<input />')
                        .val($(this).val())
                        .appendTo($('#shrimpMaster'));
                });
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6MRYB/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Does the following serve your purpose?

```
$("#shrimpfrm").children().map(function() {
    var child = $(this);
    var value = child.val();
    var container = $("#shrimpMaster");
    var field = $("<input />");

    if (child.is(":select")) {
        $(container).text(value);
            // THIS IS WHERE I'M LOST 
    }
    return null;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need to create a textbox for each `select` in `#shrimpfrm`? If so, you can use `append` to add new elements to `#shrimpMaster`.

See http://api.jquery.com/append/ or http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

```
$('#shrimpfrm select').each(function() {
  $('#shrimpMaster').append($('<input />').val($(this).val()));
});
```